# Chart showing monthly intervals and a single bar for all other data

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there way to display monthly intervals in a bar chart and the remainder as a single bar in a chart. For example May20 Jun20 Jul20 Aug20 Sep20 Oct20 [The remaining data]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a report with two different grains (Month-Year) and a group of Month-Years.

In order to achieve your desired result, you will need to do four things:

1. Create a summary table that summarises and groups by Month-Year for your range
2. Create a summary table of the "All The rest"
3. Union the two summaries (you could collapse in to one query at this point). You will need two columns, your Period (either le May20 Jun20 Jul20 Aug20 Sep20 Oct20 or ALL) and the value.
4. Create a sort column to make sure things order correctly

This gets everything in the right grain. However, when you plot it all on one chart, the "all" bucket may distort your results with one large bar and each Month-Year being a fraction thereof.